# How to hide fixed DIV when footer is visible on screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed sidebar, which is visible all along the page when scrolling down.

The problem is that - in some cases - the sidebar is getting over the footer when reaching to the bottom of the page.

I want to hide the sidebar when the Footer is visible on screen to avoid that.
How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling  You can use that in a scroll event handler and hide the div if it is true.

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('#sidebar').toggle(!isScrolledIntoView('#footer'));
});
```

Reference: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

The function is called on window scroll and check if `footer` is visible.
If visible, it hides `sidebar` else shows.

Comment: :visible checks that an element is not hidden, not that it is in view.  http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 3):

well... this is what I ended up with - works like a charm :)

```
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
    // Current distance from the top of the page
    var windowScrollTopView = $(window).scrollTop();

    // Current distance from the top of the page, plus the height of the window
    var windowBottomView = windowScrollTopView + $(window).height();

    // Element distance from top
    var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;

    // Element distance from top, plus the height of the element
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= windowBottomView) && (elemTop >= windowScrollTopView));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($("#footer").isVisible()) {
            $("#sidebar").addClass('hiddensidebar');
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").removeClass('hiddensidebar');
        }
    });
});
```